# lmer and plot_coefs: add values for estimates

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I need to plot my coefficient values for a linear model (`lm`). I use `plot_coef()` to plot, but plot only selected variables. But `plot_coef()` does not allow to add values of those estimates to the plot so that they actually show as numbers?

```
states <- as.data.frame(state.x77)
fit1 <- lm(Income ~ Frost + Illiteracy + Murder +
             Population + Area + `Life Exp` + `HS Grad`,
           data = states, weights = runif(50, 0.1, 3))

plot_summs(fit1, 
           coefs = c("Frost Days" = "Frost", "% Illiterate" = "Illiteracy"),
           scale = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may get you started:

```
library(jtools)
library(ggplot2)
p <- plot_summs(fit1, 
           coefs = c("Frost Days" = "Frost", "% Illiterate" = "Illiteracy"),
           scale = TRUE)
p + 
    geom_label(aes(label = round(estimate)))+
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

You get this:

[image]

If you want to be in better control of the final product, it would be easier to get the data using:

```
df <- broom::tidy(fit1, conf.int = TRUE)
```

Then, use `ggplot()`.